# When Select replacing comma with dot is truncating values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to convert a `varchar` column where decimal separator is `','`.
The workaround found was replace comma to dot but SQL Server is automatically rounding it up. See below example:

`2018-10-08  -8679.95    -8679,94711560794`

```
select DATA, REPLACE([PL]*1,',','.') , PL from TB_BOOK
```

Please, anyone know How can a get the value with all decimals?

Comment: Please post code that creates and loads a schema. It is easy to do and will allow us to visualize your desired outcome with your actual data. More insights here: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Use this tool to generate [ASCII tables](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/). Hope this helps get you more answers!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach to replace `,` with `.` is ok.

However on top of it you need to explicitly `CAST` the string to a number with enough decimals (`FLOAT`, `DECIMAL(p, s)`, ...).

```
SELECT DATA, CAST(REPLACE([PL],',','.')  AS FLOAT), PL from TB_BOOK
```

Comment: welcome @user9585960 : is this solution working for your use case ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but using Float, sql is floating too. And if I try with decimal(10,8) 
I receive the arithmetic overflow error.
SELECT DATA, CAST(REPLACE([PL],',','.')  AS FLOAT), PL from TB_BOOK

Comment: Decimal(10,8) can't hold this number. It holds up to 10 digits, 8 of which are decimals. Your example has 15 digits and 11 decimals. Try with higher precision decimal, like `decimal(19,11)` or `decimal(28,11)`.